# Jalar Datos de Procedimiento Almacenado en DB e imprimirlos con PrintDocument()

Tags: c#, base-de-datos, windows-forms, print

Un Saludo Cordial, espero puedan ayudarme en este trabajo Academico, tengo un formulario el cual una vez llenado me muestra un reporte "Ticket de Venta" con ReportViewer, hasta ahi todo funsiona bien logro guardar los datos del formulario en la base de datos y desde un dataset creo un reporte rdlc y lo muestro; ahoraa Tengo la necesidad de Imprimir este "Ticket de Venta" pero de forma directa a la impresora, e intentado de varias formas imprimir el Reporte rdlc pero no lo e logrado, e apredido que el ReportViewer por defecto no puede imprimir directamente a la impresora, Pues ahora e decidido mejor Imprimir mi Tiquet de Venta atravez de "Print Document()" para de esa forma hacerlo directo a la impresora sin visualizarlo, Estoy tratando de llamar los datos de la base de datos viendo algunos tutoriales en internet pero los procesos son distintos y no e tenido exito, A continuacion muestro de que forma a travez del codigo, guardo la informacion del formulario en mi base de datos y luego la visualizo en el  RV con exito:

```
private void btnGuardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TablaDetalle.AcceptChanges();

        if (cmbTipodoc2.Text == string.Empty ||
           //txtNrocomprobante.Text == string.Empty ||
           txtCliente.Text==string.Empty ||
           txtDescripcion_dmp.Text == string.Empty ||
           Convert.ToDecimal(txtImportetotal_ve.Text)<=0 ||
           Convert.ToDecimal(txtVueltoal_cliente.Text)<0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ingrese dato requerido (*)",
                            "Aviso del Sistema",
                            MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                            MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }
        else //Procedemos al guardados de los datos
        {
            string Rpta = "";
                           
            //oVe.Codigo_ve;               
            oVe.Codigo_tipdoc2 = Convert.ToInt32(cmbTipodoc2.SelectedValue);
            oVe.Nrodocumento_ve = "0";
            oVe.Fechahora_ve = Dtp_fecha.Value;
            oVe.Subtotal_ve = Convert.ToDecimal(txtSubtotal_ve.Text);
            oVe.Impuesto_ve = Convert.ToDecimal(txtImpuesto_ve.Text);
            oVe.Importetotal_ve = Convert.ToDecimal(txtImportetotal_ve.Text);
            //oVe.codigo_cl
            //oVe.Codigo_dmp
            oVe.Dineroentrega_cliente = Convert.ToDecimal(txtDineroentrega_cliente.Text);
            oVe.Vueltoal_cliente = Convert.ToDecimal(txtVueltoal_cliente.Text);
            oVe.Codigo_us = nCodigo_us;

            Datos.D_Ventas Datos = new Datos.D_Ventas();

            Rpta = Datos.Guardar_ve(nEstadoguarda, oVe);

                                
            bool esNumero = int.TryParse(Rpta, out int xCodigo);
            if (esNumero == true)
            {
                string Rpta2 = "";
                oVe.Codigo_ve = Convert.ToInt32(Rpta); //Código de venta generado

                String Codigo_ve = oVe.Codigo_ve.ToString();
                                   

                foreach (DataRow FilaTemp in TablaDetalle.Rows)
                {

                    Rpta2 = Datos.Guardar_detalle_ve(oVe.Codigo_ve,
                                                     Convert.ToInt32(FilaTemp["Codigo_pr"]),
                                                     Convert.ToDecimal(FilaTemp["Cantidad"]),
                                                     Convert.ToDecimal(FilaTemp["PUnitario"]),
                                                     Convert.ToDecimal(FilaTemp["Total"]),
                                                     Convert.ToBoolean(FilaTemp["Aplica_descuento"]));
                    if (Rpta2.Equals("OK"))
                    {
                        //OK
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Item no procesado: " + Rpta2, "Aviso del Sistema", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                    }
                }

                nEstadoguarda = 0;                    
                oVe.Codigo_cl = 0;
                oVe.Codigo_tipdoc2 = 0;
                oVe.Codigo_dmp = 0;
                this.Limpiatexto();
                this.Estadotexto(false);
                this.Estadobotones(true);
                MessageBox.Show("Los datos han sido guardados correctamente",
                                "Aviso del Sistema",
                                MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                                MessageBoxIcon.Information);
          
                Presentacion.Reportes.Frm_Rpt_Imprimirventa oRpt = new Presentacion.Reportes.Frm_Rpt_Imprimirventa();

                 oRpt.txtp01.Text = oVe.Codigo_ve.ToString() ;
                oVe.Codigo_ve = 0;
                oRpt.ShowDialog();


            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(Rpta);
            }
        }
    }
```

A Partir de  Este Esenario Como puedo jalar los datos desde mi procedimiento almacenado en la base de  datos  ?

Al momento ya tengo el contro Print Document() de esta forma :

```
printDocument1 = new PrintDocument();
               PrinterSettings ps = new PrinterSettings();
               printDocument1.PrinterSettings = ps;
               printDocument1.PrintPage += Imprimir;
               printDocument1.Print();
```

Mi evento Imprimir :

```
 private void Imprimir(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        Font font1 = new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point);
        Font font2 = new Font("Arial", 8, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point);
        Font font3 = new Font("Arial", 7, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point);
        int ancho = 250;
        int y = 20;

        

e.Graphics.DrawString("logo: "+ logo_em, font2, Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(0, y += 20, ancho, 20));
        e.Graphics.DrawString("nombre empresa: "+ nombre_em, font2, Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(0, y += 60, ancho, 20));
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Ruc: "+ nrodocumento_em, font2, Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(0, y += 20, ancho, 20));
        e.Graphics.DrawString("direccion empres : "+ direccion_em, Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(0, y += 20, ancho, 20));
        e.Graphics.DrawString("telefono empresa: "+ telefono_em, font2, Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(0, y += 20, ancho, 20));
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Ticket #: "+ codigo_ve, font2, Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(0, y += 20, ancho, 20));
        e.Graphics.DrawString("fechahora venta: "+ fechahora_ve, font2, Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(0, y += 20, ancho, 20));
        e.Graphics.DrawString("usuario: "+ usuario, font2, Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(0, y += 20, ancho, 20));
        e.Graphics.DrawString("nombre cliente: "+ nombre_cl, font2, Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(0, y += 20, ancho, 20));
        e.Graphics.DrawString("--------- PRODUCTOS --------- ", font2, Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(0, y += 30, ancho, 20));
        e.Graphics.DrawString("descripcion producto" + descripcion_pr, font1, Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(0, y += 20, ancho, 20));
        e.Graphics.DrawString("cantidad: "+ cantidad, font2, Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(0, y += 20, ancho, 20));
        e.Graphics.DrawString("punitario: "+ punitario, font2, Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(0, y += 20, ancho, 20));
        e.Graphics.DrawString("total: "+ total, font2, Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(0, y += 20, ancho, 20));
        e.Graphics.DrawString("aplica descuento: "+ aplica_descuento, font2, Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(0, y += 20, ancho, 20));
        e.Graphics.DrawString("importetotal venta: "+ importetotal_ve, font2, Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(0, y += 20, ancho, 20)); }
```

Esos son los campos que necesito jalar de la base de datos

Que Opciones tengo para recorrer los datos que genera el procedimiento almacenado, obtenerlos  e imprimirlos; segun la forma como esta planteada el evento para guardar a informacion en la BD,

Gracias por Atender esta Pregunta y ayudarme en la solucion.